# MVC ViewModel display

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am frustrated. I have a series of tables where I am trying to display fields from one model into another model's view. This is my table structure - [image]

I am attempting to display Device, Status and Location fields in DeviceLog's detail view. I have created my own device model.

```
public class DeviceLogIndexData
{
    public IEnumerable<DeviceLog> DeviceLogs { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<DeviceStatu> DeviceStatus { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<DeviceLocation> DeviceLocations { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Location> Locations { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Status> Status { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Device> Devices { get; set; }

 }
```

and have made several ways to use this. My latest attempt was -

```
var devicelog = new DeviceLogIndexData();
        devicelog.DeviceLogs = db.DeviceLogs
            .Include(d => d.Device)
            .Include(d => d.Device.DeviceStatus.Select(s => s.Status))
            .Include(d => d.Device.DeviceLocations.Select(x => x.Location))
            .OrderBy(d => d.DeviceLogID);

        devicelog = devicelog.DeviceLogs.Where(d => d.DeviceLogID == id.Value);
```

Now I am just totally frustrated and confused on how to use my ViewModel.

Comment: what does your viewmodel look like? And what is DeviceLogIndexData?

Comment: DeviceLogIndexData is my viewModel

Comment: I updated the answer with the info you provided.

Answer (score 0):

You want to project into your view model

```
var devicelog = db.DeviceLogs
            .Include(d => d.Device)
            .Include(d => d.Device.DeviceStatus.Select(s => s.Status))
            .Include(d => d.Device.DeviceLocations.Select(x => x.Location))
            .Where(d => d.DeviceLogID == id.Value)
            .Select(d => new DeviceLogIndexData { Name = d.Device.Name, ... }).ToList();
```

This is all pseudo code.  so you may need to play around with it a little.

Where your view model class looks something like this

```
public class DeviceLogIndexData {
public string Name {get;set;}
public string Status {get;set;}
public string Location {get;set;}
}
```

Then return an `IEnumerable<DeviceLogIndexData>` to your view.

Comment: When I got to the point of { d.Device.somefield,... I was not given any option of 'd' or any variation to get to a field name.

Comment: Are the public strings the fields I want to display? I tried adding Status and it will still not let me add Status in the brackets. So frustrating. I feel like I am close but just cannot seem to get over this hurdle.

Comment: Yes.  the view model properties should represent the data you want to display on your page.

Comment: I added the fields that I would like to view however when I try to add for instance Status. i declare my public string Status in my ViewModel. Whne I try to add it to my Select statement I get as far as Status = d.Device.DeviceStatus and then I would expect that I would have a choice to have the option of Status (the next table to get to the Status field) instead my choices are items like 'add', 'all', 'any', 'equal',....